# C++: How can I make an integer filter with only <iostream> library?

Tags: filter

(I don't have much english vocabulary, so sry for this weird try of english)

Hi guys! I'm new at C++ and I need to know how to create a filter code that help me at only accept **int**-*eger* numbers. I need that this code use only the 'iostream' library. This is because my teacher don't let us use another kind of library (we are new at C++ coding).

---

Here I put an example of what I have at this moment:

```
 # include <iostream>
 # include <limits> //I should't use this library

using namespace std;
int main() {

   int value = 0;

   cout << "Enter an integer value: ";
   while(!(cin >> value)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << endl <<"Value must be an integer"<< endl << endl; //This line needs <limits>
        cout << "Enter another integer value: " ;
   }
}
```

But this code have some inconvenients:

1. I'm using "#include 'limits'" library and I shouldn't use it
2. If you enter "1asd" it takes the "1" value, give it like if its correct and it isn't true

Do you guys have any solution for this situation? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use `limits`? `If you enter "1asd" it takes the "1" value, give it like if its correct and it isn't true` This is how `istream` works. If you don't want it this way, read line by line and parse the number yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check if the bytes that the user entered are numerals like below.  If all the bytes of the entered string are numerals (ie between characters 0 and 9), then the entire string is an integer.  Except first byte of the string can be a '+', '-', a space/tab or just the first numeral in the number.  (Thanks Zett42).

```
std::cout << "Enter an integer value: ";
std::string res1;
std::cin >> res1;
std::string::iterator it;
for ( it = res1.begin() ; it < res1.end(); it++)
{   std::cout << "checking " << *it << ' ';
    if (!( '0' <= *it && *it <= '9' )) {
        std::cout << "this is a numeral\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "you entered: " << *it << " -- this is *not* a numeral\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (!( *it >= '0' && *it <= '9' ))`? Also, your code doesn't allow for negative numbers.